# is there anyway we can access permissions and roles of users using vsphere rest api?

Tags: rest, vmware, vsphere

I have a site where I need to access the user's roles and permissions whose name is stored in domain controller to authenticate them. I am using Vsphere rest api but am unable to find the endpoint for it.I am wondering if it is possible anyway.

Comment: Moreover if possible, can we create such plugin using vsphere plugin  extension.

Answer (score 0):

You’re correct, the option to access or modify roles and/or permissions is not yet available through the vSphere REST APIs.

Comment: So that means their is no other way we can simplify this process from other vmware api's or  third party plugins. I tried to search about other vsphere plugins but the content is too vast.Moreover can we automate execution of  PowerCLI commands using rest api

Comment: Moreover if possible, can we create such plugin using vsphere plugin  extension.

Comment: The vSphere Web Services API is more fully featured and is probably the answer to what you need. There, you'll be looking for the AuthorizationManager object to manage permissions and/or roles: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-5/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.AuthorizationManager.html#field_detail